# How can I run python script manually in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created a Lambda and uploaded Python scripts along with the dependencies, I scheduled the Lambda to be executed three times a day, but I wanted to test it manually first so that I can have a look at the logs in CloudWatch, how can I do this?

I noticed that there is a 'Test' section but how can I configure this to tell Lambda to execute my script instead of using this 'hello world' test template, many thanks.

[image]

Comment: You can specify your own custom event, or if you don't need it, just run it and ignore the event.

Comment: Under 'Function code' section, there are File/Edit/Find/View/Go/Tools/Windows/Save/Test, but neither of them has a 'Run' button. I couldn't find the button where I can literally click on it an run the script in AWS console, Do you mind telling me where I can find it please? Thanks.

Comment: What is your function expecting as input ? What kind of event

Comment: You just press `Test`. Create some dummy test even if you don't need specif one, and press Test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, an AWS Lambda function is *triggered* by an event, such as an object being uploaded to Amazon S3 or a message being sent to an Amazon SQS queue.

In such situations, data about the event that triggered the function is supplied in the `event` variable passed to the function.

To simulate such events for testing purposes, the AWS Lambda console has the ability to provide a JSON event that mimics such events.

However, if your Lambda function does *not* require any input data via the `event` variable, then you can simply:

- Create a test event with *any* content, then
- Click the **Test** button

This will execute the Lambda function within the console and will immediately provide any error messages and/or display any information that is printed by your function. It is a great way to debug Lambda functions!

Answer (score 1):

It is simple, just edit the example json with your expected one.
Put a name of your testing event and click `Create`, after that you will have it saved in the dropdown on the left side of the `Test` button.

It is described also over here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/getting-started-create-function.html#get-started-invoke-manually